# How convert two Object in Object {{},{}} to Array with string [] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I want convert this object

```
const obj= {
    book:{
        title:'Harry Potter and',
        subtitle:'goblet on Fire'
    },
    video:{
        title:'The Mechanic',
        subtitle:'resurrection'
    }
}
```

and i need a array of strings

```
const arr = ['book','title','Harry Potter and','subtitle','goblet on Fire','video','title','The Mechanic','subtitle','resurrection']
```

how can i convert to this?

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: Have you tried anything? This seems rather straightforward and without a direct issue. SO isn't a code writing service. Give something a shot first and then ask if you have an issue.

Comment: What do you need this for? Notice it entirely looses the structure of the key-value pairs.

Comment: _"goblet on fire"_  seriously?

Comment: yes i know but i need this for api. in query api need: "Required The input text to translate. Provide an array of strings to translate multiple phrases. The maximum number of strings is 128."

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want by using `Object.entries()` and `Array.prototype.flatMap()` recursively, passing any detected objects you find into the same mapping function.

```js
const obj = {"book":{"title":"Harry Potter and","subtitle":"goblet on Fire"},"video":{"title":"The Mechanic","subtitle":"resurrection"}}

const entriesMapper = ([ key, value ]) => {
  return typeof value === "object"
    ? [ key, ...objectMapper(value) ]
    : [ key, value ]
}

const objectMapper = val =>
  Object.entries(val).flatMap(entriesMapper)

const t1 = performance.now()

const arr = objectMapper(obj)

const t2 = performance.now()

console.info(arr)
console.log(`Operation took ${t2 - t1}ms`)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a function that takes the object and reduces its keys into an array.

You iterate the keys of the object and see if the value if a string or object. If it's a string you simply push the key name and its value to the output array. If it's an object, you recursively call the same function again by concatenating the existing reducer array with the results of the recursive function.

```
const flattenObject = inpObj => Object.keys(inpObj)
    .reduce((acc, val, arr) => 
        typeof inpObj[val] === 'string'
            ? acc.push(val, inpObj[val]) 
            : acc.concat(val, flattenObject (inpObj[val])),
    []);
```

Comment: Should `flat` be `flattenObject`?

Comment: Yup :) Corrected it. Thanks!